# How to discard printouts when running tests

Tags: go, testing

Using Go 1.11 I have a function that prints a label above a user input. This is fine and works but when I have started to write the test for this function it prints out this label when running the tests.

I have also use `log.Print` but then in the test file adding the following

```
func init() {
  log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
}
```

This stops the `log.Print` from being displayed when running the tests. So how do I get it to do the same for any `fmt.Println`?

UPDATE

I thought I would post the func that I am testing and how I set up,

```
func checkLoop(loopCount int) int {
  var input int
  var ok bool

  for !ok {
    fmt.Printf("Input %d  ::  ", loopCount)
    ok, input = takeInput()
  }

  return input
}
```

So `takeInput()` only takes the users input, using `fmt.Scan` and checks it to see if its within a set range I want. So it returns a bool and if its false it will re-use the label to check what input number it is.

Comment: Generally speaking... don't use `fmt.Println` in your code, *especially* if you're already using a proper logger. Consistency makes everything easier.

Comment: I understand that. But log seems to add a timestamp to the output. Thats ok when its outputting an error but this is only doing a label. The idea for this is that I take 9 user inputs within a set range. If the input is not within that range it logs an error out and asks the user to try again. So when I am printing the label, its to inform the user, e.g. input 1, input 2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

`discard_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "testing"
)

func printLabel(label string) {
    fmt.Println(label)
}

func TestDiscardLabel(t *testing.T) {
    defer func(stdout *os.File) {
        os.Stdout = stdout
    }(os.Stdout)
    os.Stdout = os.NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), os.DevNull)
    printLabel("Discard:")
}

func TestPrintLabel(t *testing.T) {
    printLabel("Print:")
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test discard_test.go -v
--- PASS: TestDiscardLabel (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestPrintLabel
Print:
--- PASS: TestPrintLabel (0.00s)
PASS
$
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works just like I wanted it to. Just so I can understand, is this safe to use? Or should I be, like the answer from kostix, not be using the `fmt.P*` family of functions?

Answer (score 3):

Either you're testing on a wrong level or you're testing a wrong thing, let me explain.

- If it's for some reason valuable for you to test that
  your function prints something *and also* accepts user input,
  then go ahead and do end-to-end testing for it—that is, also test
  that it prints what it's expected to print, and once it does that, submit it some canned input and then verify it processes it the way you expect it to.

  I don't know your code but supposedly you should stop
  using `fmt.P*` family of functions—which *imply* using `os.Std{in|out|err}` and write the functions forming the core of your code accepting `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` interfaces and
  call them from the top-level code passing them `os.Stdin` and `os.Stderr` etc.

  Then, when testing, it will be easy to pass these functions
  stub (or mock) values which also satisfy the said interfaces.

  (The `fmt` package supports formatted printing using the `fmt.FP*` family of functions, where that `F` is a historical artefact meaning "file" and allows you to pass it any value implementing `io.Writer`.)
- Another possibility is that what you explained looks like
  a code smell: a function concerned with processing some input
  data has no business printing any labels anywhere.

  So it well may be that you instead should split your function
  at least in two: the "outer" one prompts the user and reads the data, and the second accepts the data and processes it.
  You then test the second one.

Comment: I am not sure I completely follow what your saying about your second point. Why should I not what I label being taking a user input? How else would I be able to tell the user what input they are on? I have updated my question to include the code function I am use and how it is in use.

Comment: My second point was about not having a lump of code in a _single_ function whcih both prints the label and processes the input. From your update it looks you're fine: you have the `takeInput()` function already, and I mean that's as per my second point, it's the function you should test. If you want to do end-to-end testing—that is, test the whole `checkLoop` function—then the way to go is as per my first point: feed verify it prints labels and feed it input; may be several times in a row.

Answer (score 1):

`fmt.Printf` use the `os.Stdout` so you can simply:

```
os.Stdout = nil
fmt.Println("Hello Gopher!")
```

or more elegant:

```
os.Stdout,_ = os.Open(os.DevNull)
fmt.Println("Hello Gopher!")
```

Hope this help

Comment: I'm against this approach. It's tinkering with the environment, and it smells. What if later in the tests something _would actually want_  to write there? For added fun, one might use `t.Parallel()` in their tests to create more hard-to-find problems ;-)

Comment: Hi @kostix I agree with you (and compliments for the great answer!) I only answer to the question without any opinion about the scope

Comment: I will also add that I have given this ago. While it does do what I want it to do, it also goes a little too far. By that I mean that it stops all print outs, not just my own. As I do like the RUN & PASS messages it logs its not all that useful.